# Open the new project in unity ：System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path

Tags: unity-game-engine

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Lx7Q.png)

After I created a new unity3d project and opened it, an error occurred in unity to enter safe mode, and the error message showed

```
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 
Could not find a part of the path 'C:\\Users\\Cowboy\\Desktop\\Library\\Bee\\artifacts\\mvdfrm\\UnityEngine.ClothModule.dll_A829A65362C85E1E.mvfrm'. 

But my project is created under E:\\UnityProject
```

Some say it's some kind of environmental issue

I can't create a new project to edit normally now.

I tried to reinstall unity hub and unity, and switched the version of the unity editor.

I also tried moving the project files to my desktop, which is the path he was looking for, but another error occurred.

Hoping there is a way for me to be able to create and edit projects normally
thank you very much.

Comment: First of all, I am very grateful to Sydney_dev who helped me modify the format of the question. I will also pay attention to the specification of the format in the future.

With the help of group friends, I tried to completely delete unity and unityhub from the computer, including the registry, but it still failed.

Due to my current level, I can only solve this exception by reinstalling the system in the classic way. Just don't know why the exception occurs.